# Toggling between image src on hover and on click

Tags: jquery

I have two versions of an image - a greyed out image and a color version of the same image. In the normal state, the image is greyed out. When hovered or clicked on, the image becomes the colored version.

I know this can be done with either `toggleClass`/`addClass`/etc or changing the `attr(src)`. I've managed to have this working with hover, but I cannot get the click element to work.

These are the images and the page I am trying to work with - http://www.expatlifeinsurance.com/contact-health-insurance/

This is the code I have right now:

```
<div id="smokers">
<img id="nosmoke" src="http://www.expatlifeinsurance.com/images/smoke_no_grey.png">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
<img id="smoke" src="http://www.expatlifeinsurance.com/images/smoke_grey.png">
</div>

$("#nosmoke")
.mouseover(function() {
this.src = this.src.replace('http://www.expatlifeinsurance.com/images/smoke_no_grey.png', 'http://www.expatlifeinsurance.com/images/smoke_no_green.png');
})
.mouseout(function() {
this.src = this.src.replace('http://www.expatlifeinsurance.com/images/smoke_no_green.png', 'http://www.expatlifeinsurance.com/images/smoke_no_grey.png');
})
.click(function() {
$(this).toggleClass("off");
if ($(this).hasClass("off")) this.src = this.src.replace(/(.*)-on(.*)/, "$1-off$2");
else this.src = this.src.replace(/(.*)-off(.*)/, "$1-on$2");
}
);
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question. ideally in a working snippet so we can see the issue.

Comment: Also note that you can achieve this in pure CSS: https://codepen.io/jahid-webdev/pen/JRPvBj although note that you'd need to amend this to use the [IE specific filter for greyscale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813142/internet-explorer-10-howto-apply-grayscale-filter) if you need IE support

Comment: you can  change it on hover and on click using jquery look at this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23959132/jquery-img-src-change-on-hover-and-on-click

Comment: @MohamedElgarnaoui I have tried this code but it did not work for me. Please see above I will edit the question.

Comment: please add your code

Comment: @MohamedElgarnaoui just did

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan this only works for hover!

Comment: @CharlotteOswald you can try my solutions it works.

Answer (score 0):

After looking for your code, I was concluded that this code work perfectly you can try this. if it help you to resolve your problem.

the click function works perfectly look at the result in the `inspect element` at your browser

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="smokers">
        <img id="nosmoke" src="http://www.expatlifeinsurance.com/images/smoke_no_grey.png">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <img id="smoke" src="http://www.expatlifeinsurance.com/images/smoke_grey.png">
        </div>

</body>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

           $("#nosmoke").mouseover(function() {
               this.src = this.src.replace('http://www.expatlifeinsurance.com/images/smoke_no_grey.png', 'http://www.expatlifeinsurance.com/images/smoke_no_green.png');
           });

           $("#nosmoke").mouseout(function() {
               this.src = this.src.replace('http://www.expatlifeinsurance.com/images/smoke_no_green.png', 'http://www.expatlifeinsurance.com/images/smoke_no_grey.png');
           });

           $("#nosmoke").click(function() {
               $(this).toggleClass("off");
               if ($(this).hasClass("off")){ 
                   this.src = this.src.replace(/(.*)-on(.*)/, "$1-off$2");
               }
               else {
                   this.src = this.src.replace(/(.*)-off(.*)/, "$1-on$2");
               }
           });
       });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: no you can see at your insepect element in your browser